# Encrypting/Salting GPS Coordinates

Tags: encryption, hash

Is there a way to encrypt/salt GPS coordinates irreversibly without the private key/salt, while conserving distance metrics?

For example, map 32.16,105.47 to some other values, but be able to calculate the distance between other mapped coordinates. Translation and rotation would work, but I doubt that is secure. I'd be okay with the distance metric requiring another secret.

Comment: This isn't a security issue but a data science issue since preserving distance is the main point.

Comment: If you can preserve distance metrics you could still trilaterate a GPS coordinate - encrypt some of your own chosen coordinates (say, the north pole, London, and NYC), calculating the distance, and then calculating which point has those distances.

Comment: This would be a better question on Crypto SE, I think. You'd need to explain your exact goal, system model, and threat model (answering questions like "what goal am I trying to achieve?", "how do the users interact?", "what threats am I trying to prevent against?", "who needs to be able to read the data?", "who needs to be able to change the data?", "who shouldn't be able to read/modify the data?", "what exact mathematical operations need to be performed on the data?"). As it stands, it sounds like you want some form of homomorphic encryption, possibly format-preserving.

Comment: I ended up writing an answer anyway because I suspect it may be more accessible than what you'd find at Crypto SE.

Answer (score 2):

Privacy-preserving distance computation on coordinates is certainly possible, with some restrictions.

The paper ["*Homomorphic Proximity Computation in Geosocial Networks*" (2016) by Hu et. al.](https://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1906&context=other) (PDF) is a quite accessible example of doing this.

The main approach they demonstrate is based on an asymmetric Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption (SWHE) scheme that supports confidentiality-preserving addition/subtraction and multiplication of ciphertexts. This means that we can perform the following calculations on ciphertexts:

$$E(m_a, k_P) + E(m_b, k_P) = E(m_a + m_b, k_P)$$

$$E(m_a, k_P) - E(m_b, k_P) = E(m_a - m_b, k_P)$$

$$E(m_a, k_P) \times E(m_b, k_P) = E(m_a \times m_b, k_P)$$

where $E(m, k_P)$ is encryption of a message $m$ with a public key $k_P$.

A person in possession of the secret key $k_S$ can decrypt a message back to its plaintext, i.e. $m = D(c, k_S)$, where $c$ is the ciphertext and $k_S$ is the secret key.

*Note: The SWHE ciphers themselves are often based around [ring learning with errors (RLWE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_learning_with_errors). The SWHE cipher implementation used by the paper linked above is described separately in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/405.pdf).*

The Euclidean distance between two points is:

$$\Delta = \sqrt{(x_a - x_b)^2 + (y_a - y_b)^2}$$

*Side note: GPS coordinates are usually expressed as WGS84, so you'll need to convert them into UTM form so that a geographical distance can be approximated using by the Euclidean distance. The homomorphic proximity computation paper linked above explains how to do this.*

Since the SWHE scheme allows for addition, subtraction, and multiplication operations to be performed on ciphertexts, the square of the distance ($\Delta^2$) can be computed homomorphically, i.e.

1. Carol generates a public key $k_P$ and a secret key $k_S$. She publishes her public key.
2. Alice's coordinates are $(x_a, y_a)$. She computes $c_{x_a} = E(x_a, k_P)$ and $c_{y_a} = E(y_a, k_P)$, resulting in $(c_{x_a}, c_{y_a})$ as her encrypted coordinates.
3. Bob's coordinates are $(x_b, y_b)$. He computes $c_{x_b} = E(x_b, k_P)$ and $c_{y_b} = E(y_b, k_P)$, resulting in $(c_{x_b}, c_{y_b})$ as his encrypted coordinates.
4. Alice gives her encrypted coordinates, $(c_{x_a}, c_{y_a})$, to Bob. Since Bob does not possess the secret key $k_S$, he cannot decrypt them and recover $(x_a, y_a)$ to discover Alice's location. But, since he does have the public key $k_P$, he can perform mathematical operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication) on those encrypted coordinates using the SWHE scheme.
5. Bob wants to compute the square of the distance between the two points, i.e. $(x_a - x_b)^2 + (y_a - y_b)^2$, but on the encrypted coordinates. He first computes $c_{x_a} - c_{x_b}$ to get $c_{\Delta x}$, and $c_{y_a} - c_{y_b}$ to get $c_{\Delta y}$, i.e. the ciphertexts of the deltas between the X and Y coordinates. He then computes $c_{\Delta x} \times c_{\Delta x}$ and $c_{\Delta y} \times c_{\Delta y}$ to get ${c_{\Delta x}}^2$ and ${c_{\Delta y}}^2$ respectively. Finally he computes ${c_{\Delta x}}^2 + {c_{\Delta y}}^2$ to get ${c_\Delta}^2$, which is the ciphertext of the square of the Euclidean distance between $(x_a, y_a)$ and $(x_b, y_b)$. He cannot compute the square root because the SWHE scheme does not support this operation on ciphertexts.
6. Bob sends ${c_\Delta}^2$ to Carol. Since Carol is in possession of the secret key $k_S$, she can decrypt it: $D({c_\Delta}^2, k_S) = \Delta^2$. She can then compute the square root of the plaintext to get $\Delta$, i.e. the Euclidean distance between the points. Since Carol is only given the ciphertext of the square of the distance, she cannot know the coordinates of Alice or Bob; only the distance between them.

In this scheme, Alice and Bob do not know the exact coordinates of the other party. Neither Alice nor Bob know how far away they are from each other, because they only work on ciphertexts provided by the other party. Carol does not know where Alice or Bob are specifically, but does know the distance between them.

It is important to note that Alice or Bob must perform the SWHE distance calculations privately, outside the view of Carol. If Carol was provided with $c_{x_a}$, $c_{x_b}$, $c_{y_a}$, or $c_{y_b}$, she could use the secret key $k_S$ to decrypt those coordinates. The calculation of ${c_\Delta}^2$ must therefore be performed by an entity who is not in possession of the secret key, otherwise they could just decrypt the coordinates.

This generally means that Alice and Bob must be active participants in the distance calculation. Carol cannot maintain a database of encrypted coordinates and arbitrarily choose to decrypt distances between those of her choosing, without the participation of the entities that provided the encrypted coordinates - if she had such a database, she could just decrypt the coordinates herself. Active participation of the entities whose positions are being operated upon (e.g. Alice, Bob) is a fundamental requirement in these systems.

In addition, Alice and Bob must be trusted not to collude with Carol. If Bob provides Alice with his encrypted coordinate, and Alice sends those encrypted coordinates to Carol, they can learn Bob's position. This also means that the communication between Alice and Bob must be secure. If an attacker, Eve, can listen in on the communication and discover the encrypted coordinate, she could pass that information to Carol. In addition, Eve must not be able to impersonate Alice and ask Bob for his encrypted coordinate. This part of the security requirement is usually solved by public key infrastructure (PKI) to determine trust, and a secure communications protocol (e.g. TLS with client certificates, or a hybrid encryption scheme like PGP) to transmit the coordinate information over.

To demonstrate why active participation is needed, consider a system that uses a one-way hash function to "encrypt" coordinates. Given a point coordinate $p$, we can compute $h = H(p)$, but given $h$ it is computationally infeasible to recover $p$. More formally, we say there exists no function $H'$ such that $H'(H(p)) = p$. This is just like a regular cryptographic hash function, but in our case it has a special property: given two hashes, $h_a$ and $h_b$, there's another function $dist(h_a, h_b)$ that will tell us the distance between the two hashed points. As such, $dist(H(p_a), H(p_b))$ equals the distance between points $p_a$ and $p_b$.

In this theoretical system, Alice could compute $h_a = H(p_a)$ and Bob could compute $h_b = H(p_b)$. Anyone with access to $h_a$ and $h_b$ can calculate $dist(h_a, h_b)$ to get the distance between Alice and Bob, in plaintext, without knowing the actual coordinates. The distance computation itself requires no active interaction between Alice, Bob, Carol, or anyone else.

The lack of interaction is the flaw. Let's say Mallory - a malicious actor - has access to just one of those coordinate hashes, e.g. $h_a$ from Alice. Mallory wants to find out where Alice is. She cannot reverse $h_a$ back into $p_a$, because the function $H(p)$ is not easily invertible. However, since Mallory can compute the distance between any two coordinate hashes, without interacting with Alice, she can repeatedly hash her own "test" coordinate $p_t$ to get $h_t$, and compute the distance between it and $h_a$.

A crude walk-based attack is as follows:

1. Mallory picks a random point $p_t$ and hash it: $H(p_t) = h_t$.
2. She computes $dist(h_a, h_t)$ to get the distance $\Delta$ between $p_a$ and $p_t$.
3. If $dist(h_a, h_t)$ is very small, e.g. under 1 meter, Mallory knows that $p_a \approx p_t$, and has found Alice's position. Otherwise she continues.
4. Mallory calculates four points moving away from $p_t$ in the north, south, east, and west directions, by a distance of $\frac \Delta 2$. This gives her $p_N$, $p_S$, $p_E$, and $p_W$.
5. She then computes the hashes $H(p_X)$ for the four points to get $h_N$, $h_S$, $h_E$, and $h_W$.
6. Mallory computes $dist(h_a, h_x)$ for each of $h_N$, $h_S$, $h_E$, and $h_W$, giving her four new distances away from $p_a$.
7. Whichever point produced the smallest distance now becomes $p_t$.
8. Mallory goes back to step 2 and tries again.

In pseudocode:

```
Point searchForPoint(HashedPoint ha)
{
  // define the maximum distance two points can be away from each other to consider them equal (e.g. 1m)
  const float EPSILON = 1.0;

  // pick a random test point to start with
  double x = rand();
  double y = rand();
  Point pt = new Point(x, y);

  // calculate the distance between that point and the target
  double distance = dist(ha, hash(pt));

  // loop until we're within range
  while (distance > EPSILON)
  {
    // calculate 4 new points, moving away from pt
    Point pN = new Point(pt.X, pt.Y + distance / 2);
    Point pS = new Point(pt.X, pt.Y - distance / 2);
    Point pE = new Point(pt.X + distance / 2, pt.Y);
    Point pW = new Point(pt.X - distance / 2, pt.Y);

    // hash the four new points
    HashedPoint hN = hash(pN);
    HashedPoint hS = hash(pS);
    HashedPoint hE = hash(pE);
    HashedPoint hW = hash(pW);

    // compute the distances away from the target
    double dN = dist(ha, hN);
    double dS = dist(ha, hS);
    double dE = dist(ha, hE);
    double dW = dist(ha, hW);

    // pick the point that produced the smallest distance to be the next pt
    double minDist = min(dN, dS, dE, dW);
    if (minDist == dN)
      pt = pN;
    else if (minDist == dS)
      pt = pS;
    else if (minDist == dE)
      pt = pE;
    else
      pt = pW;

    // update the distance
    distance = dist(ha, hash(pt));
  }
  return t;
}
```

This attack can be likened to a binary search, and has a computational complexity of $O(log \space N)$ for the size of the search space. The size of the search space is proportional to the ratio between the range of possible coordinates and the value of `EPSILON`. Since those are both constant, the attack is effectively $O(1)$. There are more optimal approaches that use triangulation, but they aren't as simple to describe.

This demonstrates why there must be separation between the entity with the ability to calculate the plaintext distance, and the entities performing the homomorphic distance calculation. If any entity has the information to perform *both* operations, that entity can break confidentiality.

One might also conceive of a system in which the computation of distances from positions is delegated to a trusted intermediary. We'll call him Ted. In such a system, Alice and Bob provide the ciphertexts for their positions to Ted. He does not have access to the secret key $k_S$, so he cannot decrypt the positions. Carol can ask Ted to compute the ciphertext for the square of the distance (i.e. ${c_\Delta}^2$) between Alice and Bob, and he can do so in the SWHE scheme. He then provides Carol with that ciphertext, which she can decrypt. Alice and Bob do not directly talk to Carol. Neither Alice nor Bob are required to participate after they have provided their encrypted positions to Ted.

However, this system turns out to have some pretty major downsides:

- Ted must be absolutely trusted. If Ted colludes with Carol, he can pass the encrypted positions to her and reveal the locations of Alice and Bob.
- Ted must only respond to requests to calculate the distance between known users, rather than a known user and an arbitrary encrypted position. Otherwise, Ted can be leveraged by Carol to perform the same search attack as shown above.
- Alice and Bob must still be trusted not to collude with Carol, otherwise they could fraudulently report their positions to aid Carol in a search attack against the other.
- If Ted does not rate-limit requests, Carol can ask Ted for the distance between every user, then perform cluster analysis to identify associations between users.

More generally, when the user does not need to explicitly consent to the distance between them an another user being calculated, many attacks are possible:

- Carol can log distances between users over time in order to discover patterns of movement. By looking for users that do not move relative to each other during certain time periods, locations can be narrowed down to a rough timezone. This can be combined with cluster analysis to identify cities.
- If Carol can poll for distances between users at a high rate, she can estimate the relative velocity of those users. This can be correlated against major roads and public transport routes to identify their location.
- If Carol can learn the position of a small number of users, she can perform a triangulation attack against other users by asking for the distances between them.

In summary, homomorphic cryptography *can* be used to solve this problem, but you must be very careful to ensure that the security requirements are met.

Comment: The catch with this answer's cryptosystem is that it allows anyone to compute the _encrypted_ distance from encrypted coordinates. With ability to decipher the distance comes the ability to decipher the coordinates, and my understanding of the question is that's unwanted! But, it's unavoidable that with knowledge of 2 points and ability to compute distance, we can find location on the plane (or surface of a sphere), within an uncertainty of having 2 possible solutions. As so usual, homomorphic encryption nicely solves a problem that's different from the one users would want to solve.

Comment: @fgrieu Anyone can calculate the _ciphertext_ of the distance, not the plaintext distance. You need the secret key to recover $\Delta^2$ from ${c_\Delta}^2$. You're correct that if you can decipher the distance you can decipher the coordinates, but that's why I was so careful to explain that the ${c_\Delta}^2$ calculation must be performed by entities that do not have access to $k_S$, and parties privy to ${c_x}a$, ${c_x}b$, ${c_y}a$, and ${c_y}b$ must be trusted not to collude with whoever has $k_S$.

Comment: Yes. My point is that knowledge of the secret/private secret key also allows to decipher all the coordinates. Which I believe is unwanted (if unavoidable).

Comment: Indeed, that is unfortunately a problem. The delegation approach helps a bit there, but obviously the trust model is rather fragile.

Answer (score 0):

If we have at least 3 encrypted points, and the ability to calculate distances we learn the locations up to an unknown rotation and translation(Maybe randomly mirror as well)

So though just applying secret translation and rotation still reveals a lot of information I don't think you can do better. As anything preserving distances will reveal the same with very few points.

Take the first point place it at 0,0 take the next point place it on the equator to the east at the required distance take third point place it at the northern hemisphere at the required distance from the previous two points. Any further point added has only one location it can be on the globe(Assuming the first 3 aren't all on a great circle). With random rotation, translation, mirroring you get the same effect exactly. You can place the first 3 points with the exact same limitations and then locations of all other points is fixed.